# How to change the startup screen of Servicemix

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I want to change the startup screen of servicemix which is as below,

```
 ____                  _          __  __ _      
/ ___|  ___ _ ____   _(_) ___ ___|  \/  (_)_  __
\___ \ / _ \ '__\ \ / / |/ __/ _ \ |\/| | \ \/ /
 ___) |  __/ |   \ V /| | (_|  __/ |  | | |>  < 
|____/ \___|_|    \_/ |_|\___\___|_|  |_|_/_/\_\

  Apache ServiceMix (4.4.1-fuse-01-13)

karaf@root>
```

to my custom name. 
If its possible may I know the procedure

Regards,
Bharani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceMix 4.4.1 uses Karaf 2.2.x. You can find a branding how-to for Karaf 2.2.x here http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.2.x/developers-guide/branding-console.html.

ServiceMix is a custom distribution of Karaf and the branding used in ServiceMix is a customized Karaf branding. You can find the branding module for ServiceMix 4.4.x here https://github.com/apache/servicemix4-features/tree/features-4.4.x/branding. This is what you exactly need. You can use this project as a template and implement your branding in the same way. The how-to mentioned above should help you to install the bundle in the correct location.